# cakephp auth component allow redirect issue

Tags: redirect, components, cakephp-1.3, authentication

I am having problem with Auth component when I use `$this->Auth->allow('index','view');` 
I am getting /users/login has resulted in too many redirects when I use `$this->Auth->allow('*')` it works fine. I am using cakephp 1.3.12 here is app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Auth','Session');
    function beforeFilter(){    
         $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    } 
}
```

I changed the app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Auth','Session');
    function beforeFilter(){    
        $this->Auth->allow(array('index','view','display'));
    }
}
```

users_controller.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Users';

function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow(array('login','logout'));
}

function login() {
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->redirect('/', null, false);
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I am using Apache/2.2.17 PHP/5.3.5

Answer (score 2):

Don't know but you might want to check if you have any request actions.

"If you are using requestAction in your layout or elements you should allow those actions in order to be able to open login page properly."
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1257/allow

This had me stumped for the longest time.

Let's say you render an element somewhere in your template:

```
echo $this->element('comments');
```

And in views/elements/comments.ctp you have something that requests an action like

```
$comments = $this->requestAction('comments/index');
foreach($comments as $comment) {
 // print stuff
}
```

In your CommentsController your have to:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
}
```

Notice you are requesting an index action from your comments controller in your element. That's why you have to allow 'index' for that specific controller.

I haven't seen this problem properly addressed anywhere. Hope that's what is causing your error.

Answer (score 1):

its an array =)

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('index','view'));
```

your getting the `too many redirects` message becasuse the /user/login action is not accessible. So the server tries to display the login page, but it can't, because regular non-connected users dont have acces to /user/login. And when a user doesn't have access to a page, the server will redirect him to the login page... so you see, its an infinite loop.

The /user/login action should be authorized to everyone. Your `Users` controller should look like this:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Users';
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow(array('login','logout'));
}

function login(){
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->redirect('/', null, false);
    }
}

    //if you're using prefix routes. 
function admin_login(){
    $this->redirect('/users/login');
}
```

if this doesn't the problem, maybe you're redirecting the page in the routes.php

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for quick reply I tried that one as well but no luck. even it doesnt allow index and view actions

Comment: thank you for your comment I tried that one but no luck. I cleared cache and everything on the browser but it says too many redirect

Comment: thank you very much but it didnt work for me. I also added routes.php I can not see any problem it is really weird

Comment: I found the problem I was forgot that I was using requestAction when I allow that problem solved. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong.How can app can get to know that which of your controller action you are trying to controller.Do it from your controller.

remove this from app

> $this->Auth->allow(array('index','view','display'));

try this in your app controller with needed change

```
        $this->Auth->loginError = "Wrong credentials. Please provide a valid username and password.";

        $this->Auth->authError = "You don't have sufficient privilege to access this resource.";

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
```

do this from your user controller

```
$this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
$this->Auth->allow('*');
```

And in your login dont do anything all of your redirect and all will be doing by app controller.

If you have any doubt regarding this mail me

> jafarkv9@gmail.com